# VB .NET HttpListener and ipv6

Tags: vb.net, http, server, get, ipv6

I have got a http server based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/20910606/7786925 but I have noticed it is not reachable with ipv6. Only ipv4 is working.
I do not get the prefix work with a ipv6 address, even if the prefix is "http://[ipv6_address]:8080/HttpListener/".

Is it possible and if yes, how?

Thank you very much.