# VB.net Receive Posts - Simple HTTP Server - what type of project do I use?

Tags: vb.net, http, server, project

I read with interest the post on: VB.net Receive Posts - Simple HTTP Server

[VB.net Receive Posts - Simple HTTP Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20891328/vb-net-receive-posts-simple-http-server)

It's something that I would like to experiment with, but would like to know what type of VB.NET project is this when setting up a project in Visual Studio?
The options are:
Blank App 
WPF App (.net framework)
Windows Forms App(.net framework)
Console App (.net core)
Console App (.net framework)
Class Library (.net standard)
Class Library (.net framework)
Shared Project
Class Library (legacy portable)
Class library (Universal Windows)
Windows Runtime Component (universal windows)
Until Test App (Universal Windows)

Any pointers would be appreciated, I'm a bit of a newbie when it comes to .net

Comment: That choice is based on what you want your app to do. i.e. should it just run quietly without a GUI as a service, or do you want a visual so you could maybe see post logs or something for example, or do you want this to be a library that you can reference in other projects, etc... If you talk a bit more about what you want your program to do and how you will use it, people may be able to point you towards a specific type of project.

Comment: console app most likely. It has to be something executable. Did you try any of them?

Comment: thanks mate.I basically need to get an app running that is part of a website. i,e, I have a website built already (javascript) but want to make calls to be able to pass files back to the client when the call is made.
Basically, an extension of the website (currently hosted on IIS), but happy for the port to be different and domain the same.

Comment: If you already have a .net web project on the server, you can just add a Generic Handler (.ashx) page to it that can act as a file server, that basically skips the normal aspx page lifecycle and lets you process a post and write binary data or text straight to the response stream. If this has to be on a different port and you want it as a separate process on the server, I think Standard Desktop > Windows Service would be good, that will just always be running in the background and doesn't have a GUI, can be stopped/started automatically and managed just like any other windows service.

Comment: you could consider a Web API project instead of effectively making your own web server

Comment: thank you all for your replies on this, gives me a lot to think about.
I will probably go for the windows service to start with, I have no .net on the web server as yet, it's all Javascript/HTML and CSS.